# Question regarding slowdowns and swiping

Tags: lagging

2 questions regarding my note 4.

My phone randomly slows down / freezes. Especially when calling up a keyboard and start typing, it freezes.. very annoying.

I have a feeling, the keyboard is getting killed by the OS and when I want to type something it takes up a few seconds to "boot up".

Also looking at monitoring apps, I see that Android services consistently is taking up CPU time. Cpu usage is almost always hovering at 30% without doing anything with occasional spikes. When I want to d something that happens to conincide with that spike, thats when the lag spikes come.

Is there a way to find out what app is causing this? "Android Services" doesnt really say much..

Another question is regarding swiping. This might be a nitpick, but I noticed on some apps in order to swipe, I have to do the swiping motion for a pretty long distance. On apps like inbox, it's enough to do a little flick. On others like MS Outlook, I have to keep my finger glued to the screen for almost a quarter of the width of the screen, otherwise it will bounce back.

I think what is happening is, the dev optimized the swiping motion to be on a smaller screen and didnt take into account larger devices. Is there something I can do about this?